# Sub for Creating a Pie Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Sub to create a pie chart:

```
Sub CreatePieChart(dataSource As String, chartTitle As String, positionX As Double, positionY As Double)
    Dim newChart As Shape

    Range(dataSource).Select
    Set newChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

    With newChart
        .Select
        .Chart.ChartType = xlPie
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(dataSource)
        .Chart.chartTitle.Select
        .Chart.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
        .Top = positionY
        .Left = positionX

    End With

End Sub
```

It works perfectly when I call it for the first time, but when I want to create a second chart I get the following error:

*Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error*

The error occurs on this line:

> Set newChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

I hope you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance

EDIT:

1st call of the sub:

> CreatePieChart "A1:B6", "first", 10, 200

2nd call:

> CreatePieChart "A1:A6,D1:D6", "second", 10, 400

Comment: can you just add the different calls to `CreatePieChart` to see which parameters are passed each time?

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various thing I came up with this solution which works with the set of datas I choose (so I hope it will work for you too):

**Solution:**

```
Private Sub call_test()    ' No interest but to call CreatePieChart 
    CreatePieChart "A1:B6", "first", 10, 200
    CreatePieChart "A1:A6,D1:D6", "second", 10, 400   
End Sub

Sub CreatePieChart(dataSource As String, chartTitle As String, positionX As Double, positionY As Double)

    Dim newChart As Shape
    Set newChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

    With newChart
        .Chart.ChartType = xlPie
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(dataSource)
        .Chart.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
        .Top = positionY
        .Left = positionX
    End With

End Sub
```

My set of datas:

```
void  void    void          
1     4     7
2     7     4
3     8     2
4     4     1
5     2     2
6     9     2
```

What was causing the error for me was the abuse of `.Select`: You can't use `Select` on disjoined Ranges, that's why I didn't worked with `"A1:A6,D1:D6"`. I had to do some other modifications but it works for me.

**NOTE:** To Select disjoined ranges, use `Union`: cf [Ranges on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Just found out that the Select stuff was causing the error but didn't know why ;)

Comment: @oHoodie Nice you found the solution by yourself. My advice is to try to avoid `Select` as much as possible, it is not really efficient and can lead to hard to track bugs

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution which is working, I just don't know why. Only thing I changed is I left out all the selecting. New code:

```
Sub CreatePieChart(dataSource As String, chartTitle As String, positionX As Double, positionY As Double)
    Dim newChart As Shape

    Set newChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

    With newChart
        .Chart.ChartType = xlPie
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(dataSource)
        .Chart.chartTitle.Text = chartTitle
        .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
        .Top = positionY
        .Left = positionX   
    End With

End Sub
```

It's really strange but at least it's working now. Thank you for your effort.